# How can I use a javascript function globally in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

How can I use a javascript function globally in Drupal 7.

I have my javascript file set up like this and add it using drupal_add_js():

```
(function($) {
  function add_if_country_is_not_usa() {
   // Check what country it is

   // Update text, image, etc.. of a block.
  }
});
```

In my block WYSIWIG I added the following code (The reason I add it in the WYSIWIG  is because I want it to update before the page is fully rendered):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  add_if_country_is_not_usa();
</script>
```

But I get the following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: add_if_country_is_not_usa is not defined 
(anonymous function)

I read about adding functions to Drupal behaviors but that happens on document ready. I want to run the function as soon as the block is shown.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Either define in the global scope, or do like below:

```
(function($) {
  function add_if_country_is_not_usa() {
   // Check what country it is

   // Update text, image, etc.. of a block.
  }

  // set as a property of the global object `window`
  window.add_if_country_is_not_usa = add_if_country_is_not_usa;
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get the above to work. How do I define the function in global scope?

Comment: @albertski What's the error you got, make sure the code included before you use the function.

Comment: I think I got the same error. I believe it has to do something with Drupal or perhaps I did something wrong. Anyways I was able to get it to work using namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way but I ended up being able to get it work using a namespaces.  I call myGlobalObject.add_if_country_is_not_usa() from my block and it works now.

```
var myGlobalObject = mySingleGlobalObject || { 'country': {} };

(function ($) {
   myGlobalObject.country = '';

   myGlobalObject.add_if_country_is_not_usa = function() {      
     // Check what country it is

     // myGlobalObject.country = 'US';
   }
})(jQuery);
```